# How to get Notifications from Broadcast Receivers on Redmi Phones?

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, redmi-device

I have developed a wallpaper App which triggers a `notification` "Pic of the day" between 7AM - 10 PM when the internet is connected for the first time .

Everything is working fine except in Redmi Phones(due to MIUI) . It is not even triggering `broadcast receivers` due to which i can't get notifications .

I tried things from given hyperlink but nothing worked ["How to Get Notifications from Redmi?"](https://www.androidcentral.com/how-fix-push-notifications-miui-8)

Usage of the App directly depends on Redmi users as they are increasing day by day ,moreover i can't tell the user to do settings in order to get notifications from my App.

If anyone can help doing it programatically then it would be a good solution !

Comment: could you explain why being Redmi affects this function?
if user disable notification, no one on earth can get a notification except if it have system access/be a system app.

Comment: That is because the redmi  has a seperate ui for its phones called miui which has certain features like disabling the background tasks for optimization/battery saving . And even if user is not disabling redmi phones have some by default settings which turns off the notification.